# jquery "this" when in collection context

Tags: javascript, jquery

We all know that $("p") is a general selection, selecting all paragraphs of a page. Considering this, what would "this" refer to in the following code:

```
$( "p" ).fadeIn( 750, function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "lookAtMe" );
});
```

Would "this" refer to all the paragraphs or just the first one in the collection created by $("p")?

Comment: [.fadeIn()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.fadeIn) -> [.animate()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.animate) -> [.each()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.each)

Answer (score 2):

In the code you provided, `this` refers to each individual `p` element. The provided callback function will be called once per `p` in the selection that is fading in.

It doesn't make a significant difference in your code as provided, but it's important to realize that `fadeIn` will be added to the `fx` queue on each of the selected elements. If one of the elements in the selection is already animating, the `fadeIn` effect will not happen until the rest of the queue is complete, so it's possible that some complete callbacks will happen at different times.